# nvim-qt on Windows, cursor highlight color not work

Tags: neovim, highlight

I use nvim-qt on windows 10, and i set the cursor highlight color by:

```
highlight Cursor  guifg=Red guibg=Green
highlight iCursor guifg=Red guibg=Green
set guicursor=n:block-Cursor/lCursor
```

but it does not work, how do I set cursor color?